# Istanbul jasmine-node issue on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, istanbul, jasmine-node

Trying to run istanbul with jasmine-node

> Running: node C:\myproject\project1\node_modules.bin\jasmine-node.CMD
>   test No coverage information was collected, exit without writing
>   coverage information
>   C:\myproject\project1\merg\node_modules.bin\jasmine-node.CMD:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF
>   EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
>                                                                ^ SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token    at
>   Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)    at Module._compile
>   (module.js:528:28)    at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:565:10)    at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous
>   function) [as .js]
>   (C:\myproject\project1\merg\node_modules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:109:37) 
>   at Module.load (module.js:473:32)    at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:432:12)    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)    at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)    at runFn
>   (C:\myproject\project1\merg\node_modules\istanbul\lib\command\common\run-with-cover.js:122:16)
>   at
>   C:\myproject\project1\merg\node_modules\istanbul\lib\command\common\run-with-cover.js:251:17
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\itsme\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "run" "test-cov" npm ERR! node v6.6.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7 npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! Merg@0.4.0 test-cov: `istanbul cover --report
>   cobertura --include-all-sources jasmine-node test` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the Merg@0.4.0 test-cov script
>   'istanbul cover --report cobertura --include-all-sources jasmine-node
>   test'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and
>   npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with
>   the Merg package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the
>   author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     istanbul cover
>   --report cobertura --include-all-sources jasmine-node test npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs Merg npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you
>   can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls Merg npm ERR! There
>   is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\myproject\project1\merg\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Try `"node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha"` instead of `"_mocha"`.